# Error when i am trying to remove an element

Tags: javascript

In the following code i need to write the function of removing the element of the class (devil), i wrote the function for removing but something is wrong. Thank-you for your time!

**html code**

```
<html>
    <title>Test</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="draw()" onclick="shoot(event)">
            <div id="box" onmousemove="move(event)">
                <img id="aim"src="img/1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div id="borderleft"></div>
            <div id="info">     
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**css code**

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}
img{
    position: absolute;
}

#box{
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    cursor: none;
    z-index: 2;

}
#info{
    width: 524px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
}

#borderleft{
    top:-25px;
    height: 525px;
    width: 25px;
    margin-left: 499px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
}

#info, #border{

    z-index: 3;
}


.devil{
    z-index: 1;

}
```

and JavaScript code

```
function move(e){
  if(e.clientX<500 &&  e.clientY<500){
   // alert(e.clientX+":"+e.clientY)
  //cautam divul info
  info=document.getElementById("info")

  //schimbam textul din terior
  //innerHTML-
  info.innerHTML=e.clientX+":"+e.clientY

  //miscam imaginea cu mouse
  //gasim imaginea dupa id
  aim=document.getElementById("aim");
  aim.style.left=(e.clientX-25)+"px";
  aim.style.top=(e.clientY-25)+"px";
  }
  //animatia se face mai bine in pozitia absolute
  //la absolute update se face doar la absolut div da la relative la toata pagina

}

//functia care va desena imagini
function draw(){
 // generam cantitate de obiecte
 N_objects=parseInt(Math.random()*10);

 // ciclu-adaugam imaginile in boxa
  //gasim box
  box=document.getElementById("box");

  for(i=0;i<N_objects;i++){
    //cream elemente noi
    o=document.createElement('img');
    //setam adresa
    o.src="img/2.png";
    //adaugam element in box
    box.appendChild(o);

          o.setAttribute("class","devil")
    //coordonate aleatoare
    o.style.left=parseInt(Math.random()*449)+'px';
    o.style.top=parseInt(Math.random()*449)+'px';
   }



}

 function shoot(e){
// alert(e.clientX+":"+e.clientY)
devil=document.querySelectorAll('.devil')
//verificam daca am nimerit in toate imaginile
for(i=0;i<devil.length;i++)
{
  if (e.clientX>parseInt(devil[i].style.left) )
    if(e.clientY>parseInt(devil[i].style.top) )
      if(e.clientX<parseInt(devil[i].style.left)+50 )
        if(e.clientY<parseInt(devil[i].style.top)+50 )
         {
          element=getElementByClass("devil");
          element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
         };
}
```

}

In the function shoot, inside of the if statements needs to me a function that removes the element with (devil) class, i wrote  this lines but i have an error.

```
element=getElementByClass("devil");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
```

Comment: Why aren't you declaring any variables? Dangerous!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I am new to JavaScript that's why i dont have variables, and in this code i dont see were do i need variables. The error: Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementByClass is not defined

Comment: Because it's "Elements"<-----. It returns a collection. [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

Comment: so what should i change to work : ? )

Comment: I think you need to revise some of the basics of the language, like variable declarations, and global scope. I'd start from scratch here http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics

Comment: :) thx for this useful information, but can you tell me it exist this function in javascript getElementByClassName(), and how can i find the parentNode of the class elelemnt?

Comment: @Chris `lement=getElementByClass("devil");`into `lement=getElementsByClass("devil");`(make a letter comparision.

Comment: @Chris If you uses HTML5 with it new Javascript version, then exists it by default, else you have to look at Stackoverflow where an free implementation is. Also e. g. Jquery supports this method.

Comment: See link I posted, plural matters, case matters. Unless you defined these somewhere, `getElementByClass` and `getElementByClassName` don't exist. You need `document.getElementsByClassName` which returns a collection, or you can try `document.querySelector(selector)` which returns an Element. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) has all this info and more, that's your main reference.

Comment: ok, i will take a look, and can someone tell me what is the parrent for devill class elelemnt in my code, i need to understand who is the parrent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So do you have a method `getElementByClass` defined somewhere?

There is no getElementByClass in JavaScript, there is a [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) which returns a collection.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("devil")[0];
element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
```

Comment: THx, your line of code works, but can you tell me what dose [0] mean for?

Comment: `getElementsByClassname` returns a set of elements. The bracket notation [0] returns the first element from the set.

Comment: oh, but how can i return the element in my case on which i click?

Answer (score 0):

*IDs* are restricted to be unique in HTML (some web designers don't seem to think so. If you find one of them, punch them). *Classes* are not - and so any method finding a particular class tends to return a set of them.

If you expect to only have one of a particular HTML element, set its id instead of its class, and retrieve it with `getElementById()`.

Conversely, if you expect to have multiple of a particular element type (ie, "borderBox" or "gameEnemy") use a class, and iterate through the results of `getElementsByClassName` using a for-loop, likely performing the same operation on each of them. (If you're not familiar with for loops, you may really want to go through a JavaScript basics course)