# Elements of the same class to put in an array

Tags: javascript

How can i put all elements of the same class into an array?
In the following function i need before removing the element of the class "devil" to check if it's position corresponds to a variable, that's why i need to check an if statement from an array of all elements of "devil" class. Thank you for your time.

```
function shoot(e){
    // alert(e.clientX+":"+e.clientY)
    devil=document.querySelectorAll('.devil')
    //verificam daca am nimerit in toate imaginile
    for(i=0;i<devil.length;i++)
    {
      if (e.clientX>parseInt(devil[i].style.left) )
        if(e.clientY>parseInt(devil[i].style.top) )
          if(e.clientX<parseInt(devil[i].style.left)+50 )
            if(e.clientY<parseInt(devil[i].style.top)+50 )
             {

              var element = document.getElementsByClassName("devil")[0];
              element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
             };
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm confused. Your script looks like it already puts all elements of the same class into an array-like structure.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `nodeList`, an array like object with length, what more could you need ?

Comment: You could of course use `document.getElementsByClassName('devil');`

Comment: Crush, I already tried to write so an i have an error

Comment: There are a few things going on in [your code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048474/error-when-i-am-trying-to-remove-an-element) that could cause issues, specially all those globals. Try http://jshint.com to validate your code.

Comment: @adeneo if i will write querySelectorAll(devil) i will have all elements of the class devil together?

Comment: The nodelist is live, and you're removing elements, so you'll have issues. You have to iterate in reverse, change the loop to `for (var i=devil.length; i--;) [...`

Comment: @Chris: That's what your code is already doing: It selects all `.devil` elements, stores the collection in `devil` and then you are iterating over all those elements.

Comment: @adeneo: Not the one returned by `querySelectorAll` (which the OP already uses): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll. So no need to iterate in reverse order.

Comment: Nope, that would be static, that's the difference from getElementsByClassName

Comment: what do you think i need to do in order to remove the elements not in the order they are but only if their position is equal to a variable?

Comment: Instead of `var element = document.getElementsByClassName("devil")[0];  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);`, which always accesses *the first* `.devil` element, do `devil[i].parentNode.removeChild(devil[i])`, which will remove the element you just compared in the loop.

Comment: Are you just trying to target `devil[i]` in the loop, instead of always the first element? Not sure I get it.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you very much i was searching for your answer for 2 hours, it worked. :D can you please enplane  this line devil[i].parentNode.removeChild(devil[i])

Comment: I'm sure @FelixKling will post an answer explaining it soon.